# Map from int to type specifier

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to use a map to refer to a type specifier mainly to shorten my code from multiple uses of

```
std::unique_ptr< Class >(new class1);
```

to

```
std::unique_ptr< Class >(new sampleMap[enum1]);
```

and then define my map so that it refers each enum value (`enum1`, `enum2`, ...) to my classes (`class1`, `class2`, ...).

But I cannot define my map with the values being a type name like this

```
std::map < int, Class > mapName {
{0, class1},
{0, class1},
...
};
```

since type name is not allowed in maps.

The main reason I'm looking for an answer for this is to make my code more succinct by replacing a series of "`if`/`else if`" statements or "`switch`-case" statements into only one line of code where the output `std::unique_ptr<Class>(new class1);` is dynamically figured out through the map that I define. So, I just input the enum number and get the corresponding class instantiated for me. Otherwise, I would have to do this:

```
if (enum1 = 0)
{
    std::unique_ptr< Class >(new class1);
}
else  if (enum2 = 0)
{
    std::unique_ptr< Class >(new class2);
}
```

(or a switch-case)
But I want to do all above in one line like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Class>(new sampleMap[enum1]);
```

plus the map declaration.

Any clue how this could be done?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218012)

Comment: It's possible, with templates, to make `new type_map<some_int>::type` work, and then you can use template recursion to loop through a number of values.  But I agree with Justin, tell us what you want to accomplish, there might be an even better way.

Comment: It sounds like this might be a candidate for a template type parameter pack.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a common base class? Edit: I guess you must.

Comment: @Justin and Ben Voigt Thanks for the comments. I added more explanations to clarify why I'm asking this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot easily implement an `std::map` that will return types as values the way you are trying to do it. You would need to implement your own class that would represent types as values. However, since your goal seems to be to create instances of objects where the concrete type depends on a value, an easily solution is to make a map of functions instead. This assumes that all the types you want to support derive from a common type. Each value can hold a function which constructs the correct object. If your types do not derive from a common type, then you will need to preform further type erasure (perhaps with [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

// Simple set of classes
// Class is the base type
// Class1 and Class2 derive from Class
struct Class { virtual void func() = 0; };
struct Class1 : Class {
    void func() override { std::cout << "Class1\n"; }
};
struct Class2 : Class {
    void func() override { std::cout << "Class2\n"; }
};

// A map of factory functions
const std::map<int, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Class>()>> mapName = {
    { 1, []() {return std::make_unique<Class1>(); } },
    { 2, []() {return std::make_unique<Class2>(); } }
};

int main()
{
    auto foo = mapName.at(2)(); // Make an object of type associated with the value 2
    foo->func();                // Prints "Class2\n"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My sole intention is class instantiation and return which should happen within the map definition. So I only need to return foo and it'll do it! Thanks @Francois

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you want to use this code, you might want to do this with an `if-else` chain. `std::function`s are usually very difficult for the compiler to optimize, so if you expect this code to be called frequently enough, it's probably more efficient to just code it out:

(using [@FrançoisAndrieux's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020490/1896169))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

// Simple set of classes
// Class is the base type
// Class1 and Class2 derive from Class
struct Class {
    virtual void func() = 0;
};
struct Class1 : Class {
    void func() override { std::cout << "Class1\n"; }
};
struct Class2 : Class {
    void func() override { std::cout << "Class2\n"; }
};

std::unique_ptr<Class> make_class(int i)
{
    if (i == 0) return std::make_unique<Class1>();
    else if (i == 1) return std::make_unique<Class2>();

    throw std::out_of_range{ "Asked to construct an unknown type" };
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = make_class(1); // Make an object of type associated with the value 1
    foo->func(); // Prints "Class2\n"
    return 0;
}
```

If the number of values is large, you might gain by doing a binary search (or just a `switch`):

```
// If there are 128 elements, for example
if (!(0 <= i && i < 128)) throw std::out_of_range{ "..." };

if (i < 64) {
    if (i < 32) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

It's messy but it's only in one place.

Comment: I want to prevent using if statements as I mentioned in the question. The main reason is brevity. Otherwise, you're right. It would work with if or switch statements.

Comment: @VahidZadeh If you compare the code size of both approaches, you'll find that they are basically the same.

Comment: That's probably true. But my code will be more legible if all I need to define is a map instead of multiple if statements. Again, that's mainly because I'm looking for brevity and readability. Otherwise, your suggestion may also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To make a more optimizable version, you can do some minimal metaprogramming / expression templates:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// Simple set of classes
// Class is the base type
// Class1 and Class2 derive from Class
struct Class {
    virtual void func() = 0;
};
struct Class1 : Class {
    void func() override { std::cout << "Class1\n"; }
};
struct Class2 : Class {
    void func() override { std::cout << "Class2\n"; }
};

template<typename R, typename SwBase, typename T, typename F>
struct Switch
{
    SwBase base;
    T value;
    F fn;

    constexpr Switch(SwBase base, T value, F fn)
        : base{ std::move(base) }
        , value{ std::move(value) }
        , fn{ std::move(fn) }
    {}

    constexpr R operator()(T val) const {
        if (value == val) return fn();
        return base(val);
    }
};

template<typename R, typename SwBase, typename T, typename F>
constexpr auto make_switch_impl(SwBase&& swb, T&& t, F&& f)
{
    return Switch<R, std::decay_t<SwBase>, std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<F>> {
        std::forward<SwBase>(swb),
        std::forward<T>(t),
        std::forward<F>(f),
    };
}

template<typename R>
constexpr auto make_switch(char const* failMsg)
{
    return [=](auto&&) -> R { throw std::out_of_range{ failMsg }; };
}

template<typename R, typename T, typename F, typename... Args>
constexpr auto make_switch(char const* failMsg, T&& val, F&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
    return make_switch_impl<R>(
        make_switch<R>(failMsg, std::forward<Args>(args)...),
        std::forward<T>(val),
        std::forward<F>(fn)
    );
}

auto make_class(int i)
{
    return make_switch<std::unique_ptr<Class>>(
        "Asked to construct an unknown type",
        0, [] { return std::make_unique<Class1>(); },
        1, [] { return std::make_unique<Class2>(); }
    )(i);
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = make_class(1); // Make an object of type associated with the value 1
    foo->func(); // Prints "Class2\n"
    return 0;
}
```

The switch statement would turn into this:

> ```
> auto make_class(int i)
> {
>     return make_switch<std::unique_ptr<Class>>(
>         "Asked to construct an unknown type",
>         0, [] { return std::make_unique<Class1>(); },
>         1, [] { return std::make_unique<Class2>(); }
>     )(i);
> }
> ```

You could also store the "switch" separately, although this makes it less optimizable (down to roughly the same level as [François Andrieux's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020490/1896169)):

```
const auto mapName = make_switch<std::unique_ptr<Class>>(
    "Asked to construct an unknown type",
    0, [] { return std::make_unique<Class1>(); },
    1, [] { return std::make_unique<Class2>(); }
);

auto make_class(int i)
{
    return mapName(i);
}
```

This version, and also raw if-else chains, let the compiler optimize the `make_class` function to the equivalent of a `switch` statement. Also, the main function:

```
int main()
{
    auto foo = make_class(1); // Make an object of type associated with the value 1
    foo->func(); // Prints "Class2\n"
    return 0;
}
```

Can be optimized to the equivalent of:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Class2\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas storing the `std::function` or the other less efficient tricks I've mentioned makes it much more difficult for the compiler to optimize it fully (I haven't found one that does).

Note that out of [GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/1zyAts), [Clang](https://godbolt.org/g/fm4yL5), [Visual C++](https://godbolt.org/g/EYLU3A), and [the Intel compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/tFRTfR), only Clang was able to completely optimize the main function using this `Switch` struct. GCC and Visual C++ were able to optimize it to a call to `Class2`'s `func()`. The Intel compiler doesn't seem to have optimized it at all (but maybe I don't know the right flags for it)